# Lambda is take more time when multiple lambdas run at same time

Tags: aws-lambda

I have problem with AWS lambda execution time.

I have 8 lambdas, each of my lambda functions get the same data from S3 and draw images then upload to S3. So I use SNS to distribute the trigger event to each lambdas.

When testing, I just run 1 of them (it call `lambda_1`), and it only take about 200s for its execution. But when I add all lambdas to SNS topic to make them run at same time, that `lambda_1` takes more than 200s event get timeout (over 300s).

The same data I use, the same configuration for both execute, the only difference is 8 lambdas are executed at same time (get trigger from SNS event).

Is it the behavior of aws lambda? I have no idea about this.

Any document or suggestion is very appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Can you time your upload to S3 to check if that gets slower with concurrent uploads?

Comment: The time for upload is fine, I want to mean that the processing for same work. I wonder that the CPU and RAM is the same in 2 cases or not?

Comment: the images you are uploading are of identical names or of different names ? also , a code snippet would be a great help for us to understand .

Comment: @tom: they're different and unique.